# How to check server connection is available or not with internet connection check mobile in android?

Tags: android, json, server, httpurlconnection, data-synchronization

I want to check server connection to know if its available or not.i want to implement auto synch data when server connection is available or not with internet connection check phone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go for workmanager for this

References :
1)  [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics)

[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)

Comment: Thank you for your response...but not solve my solution